# How to make a page responsive and not dependent on device media queries?

Tags: css

I have an example page [here](http://codepen.io/tortuga/pen/BNmZMx).

It's responsive for most mobile Apple devices, but I want to go away from this as it's a bad practice. I've used the

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px)
```

for example, but again, I want minimize the use of this and not be so dependent.

I need to catch up a little in how to use percentages for a responsive layout. What are the things that I need to change/add in order to have this fit the screen no matter what width my browser is, and no matter what device loads it up?

EDIT: I want to try to avoid to use boilerplate/framework. I want to make what I have now work if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`@media` queries aren't bad practice, in fact they are as 'fully supported' as it gets.

Check it out on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to become *less* dependant on [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)? You should want to become *more* dependant on them.

Media queries are the industry standard for creating responsive layouts - replacing most mobile-only versions of websites, JavaScript implementations, and primarily percentage based layouts. They are the most efficient and effective way of targeting multiple platforms, in modern environments.

You'll be doing yourself, and any devs who work with your code, a massive disservice by trying to avoid [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rules.